# (Flutter) Bugs in Custom datepicker model using library flutter_datetime_picker

Tags: flutter, mobile, dart

Hello I am trying to create custom datepicker using library [flutter_datetime_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker) with format (Weekday name, Day - Month - Year). This is the expected result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbSfA.png)

I successfully to create this UI. However there is bug when I pick the year, the list of months and days is not updated.

This is my custom date picker model:

```
class CustomPicker extends CommonPickerModel {
  DateTime maxTime;
  DateTime minTime;

  CustomPicker({
    DateTime currentTime,
    LocaleType locale,
    DateTime maxTime,
    DateTime minTime,
  }) : super(locale: locale) {
    this.maxTime = maxTime ?? DateTime(2049, 12, 31);
    this.minTime = minTime ?? DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    this.currentTime = currentTime ?? DateTime.now();

    if (currentTime != null) {
      if (currentTime.compareTo(this.maxTime) > 0) {
        currentTime = this.maxTime;
      } else if (currentTime.compareTo(this.minTime) < 0) {
        currentTime = this.minTime;
      }
    }
    this.currentTime = currentTime;

    _fillRightLists();
    _fillMiddleLists();
    _fillLeftLists();

    int minMonth = _minMonthOfCurrentYear();
    int minDay = _minDayOfCurrentMonth();

    super.setRightIndex(this.currentTime.year - this.minTime.year);
    super.setMiddleIndex(this.currentTime.month - minMonth);
    super.setLeftIndex(this.currentTime.day - minDay);
  }

  void _fillLeftLists() {
    int maxDay = _maxDayOfCurrentMonth();
    int minDay = _minDayOfCurrentMonth();
    this.leftList = List.generate(maxDay - minDay + 1, (int index) {
      DateTime dateTime =
          DateTime(currentTime.year, currentTime.month, minDay + index);
      return '${DateFormat("EEE").format(dateTime)} ${minDay + index}';
    });
  }

  void _fillMiddleLists() {
    int minMonth = _minMonthOfCurrentYear();
    int maxMonth = _maxMonthOfCurrentYear();

    this.middleList = List.generate(maxMonth - minMonth + 1, (int index) {
      return '${_localeMonth(minMonth + index)}';
    });
  }

  void _fillRightLists() {
    this.rightList =
        List.generate(maxTime.year - minTime.year + 1, (int index) {
      // print('LEFT LIST... ${minTime.year + index}${_localeYear()}');
      return '${minTime.year + index}${_localeYear()}';
    });
  }

  int _maxMonthOfCurrentYear() {
    return currentTime.year == maxTime.year ? maxTime.month : 12;
  }

  int _minMonthOfCurrentYear() {
    return currentTime.year == minTime.year ? minTime.month : 1;
  }

  int _maxDayOfCurrentMonth() {
    int dayCount = calcDateCount(currentTime.year, currentTime.month);
    return currentTime.year == maxTime.year &&
            currentTime.month == maxTime.month
        ? maxTime.day
        : dayCount;
  }

  int _minDayOfCurrentMonth() {
    return currentTime.year == minTime.year &&
            currentTime.month == minTime.month
        ? minTime.day
        : 1;
  }

  List<int> _leapYearMonths = const <int>[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12];

  int calcDateCount(int year, int month) {
    if (_leapYearMonths.contains(month)) {
      return 31;
    } else if (month == 2) {
      if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) {
        return 29;
      }
      return 28;
    }
    return 30;
  }

  @override
  void setLeftIndex(int index) {
    super.setLeftIndex(index);
    int minDay = _minDayOfCurrentMonth();
    currentTime = currentTime.isUtc
        ? DateTime.utc(
            currentTime.year,
            currentTime.month,
            minDay + index,
          )
        : DateTime(
            currentTime.year,
            currentTime.month,
            minDay + index,
          );
  }

  @override
  void setMiddleIndex(int index) {
    super.setMiddleIndex(index);
    //adjust right
    int minMonth = _minMonthOfCurrentYear();
    int destMonth = minMonth + index;
    DateTime newTime;
    //change date time
    int dayCount = calcDateCount(currentTime.year, destMonth);
    newTime = currentTime.isUtc
        ? DateTime.utc(
            currentTime.year,
            destMonth,
            currentTime.day <= dayCount ? currentTime.day : dayCount,
          )
        : DateTime(
            currentTime.year,
            destMonth,
            currentTime.day <= dayCount ? currentTime.day : dayCount,
          );
    //min/max check
    if (newTime.isAfter(maxTime)) {
      currentTime = maxTime;
    } else if (newTime.isBefore(minTime)) {
      currentTime = minTime;
    } else {
      currentTime = newTime;
    }

    this._fillLeftLists();
    int minDay = _minDayOfCurrentMonth();
    super.setLeftIndex(currentTime.day - minDay);
  }

  @override
  void setRightIndex(int index) {
    super.setRightIndex(index);
    //adjust middle
    int destYear = index + minTime.year;
    int minMonth = _minMonthOfCurrentYear();
    DateTime newTime;
    //change date time
    if (currentTime.month == 2 && currentTime.day == 29) {
      newTime = currentTime.isUtc
          ? DateTime.utc(
              destYear,
              currentTime.month,
              calcDateCount(destYear, 2),
            )
          : DateTime(
              destYear,
              currentTime.month,
              calcDateCount(destYear, 2),
            );
    } else {
      newTime = currentTime.isUtc
          ? DateTime.utc(
              destYear,
              currentTime.month,
              currentTime.day,
            )
          : DateTime(
              destYear,
              currentTime.month,
              currentTime.day,
            );
    }
    //min/max check
    if (newTime.isAfter(maxTime)) {
      currentTime = maxTime;
    } else if (newTime.isBefore(minTime)) {
      currentTime = minTime;
    } else {
      currentTime = newTime;
    }

    this._fillMiddleLists();
    this._fillLeftLists();
    minMonth = _minMonthOfCurrentYear();
    int minDay = _minDayOfCurrentMonth();
    super.setMiddleIndex(currentTime.month - minMonth);
    super.setLeftIndex(currentTime.day - minDay);
  }

  @override
  String leftStringAtIndex(int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < leftList.length) {
      return leftList[index];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  String middleStringAtIndex(int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < middleList.length) {
      return middleList[index];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  String rightStringAtIndex(int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < rightList.length) {
      return rightList[index];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  String leftDivider() {
    return "";
  }

  @override
  String rightDivider() {
    return "";
  }

  @override
  List<int> layoutProportions() {
    return [2, 1, 1];
  }

  String _localeYear() {
    if (locale == LocaleType.zh) {
      return '年';
    } else if (locale == LocaleType.ko) {
      return '년';
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  String _localeMonth(int month) {
    if (locale == LocaleType.zh) {
      return '$month月';
    } else if (locale == LocaleType.ko) {
      return '$month월';
    } else {
      List monthStrings = i18nObjInLocale(locale)['monthShort'];
      return monthStrings[month - 1];
    }
  }

  @override
  DateTime finalTime() {
    return currentTime;
  }
}
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem is because there is no setState to refresh another column in the right column. So, I need to create custom date picker class and change the _renderItemView method to this:

```
Widget _renderItemView(DatePickerTheme theme) {
    return Container(
      color: theme.backgroundColor ?? Colors.white,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          _renderColumnView(
              ValueKey(widget.pickerModel.currentLeftIndex()),
              theme,
              widget.pickerModel.leftStringAtIndex,
              leftScrollCtrl,
              widget.pickerModel.layoutProportions()[0], (index) {
            widget.pickerModel.setLeftIndex(index);
          }, (index) {
            setState(() {
              refreshScrollOffset();
              _notifyDateChanged();
            });
          }),
          Text(
            widget.pickerModel.leftDivider(),
            style: theme.itemStyle,
          ),
          _renderColumnView(
              ValueKey(widget.pickerModel.currentLeftIndex()),
              theme,
              widget.pickerModel.middleStringAtIndex,
              middleScrollCtrl,
              widget.pickerModel.layoutProportions()[1], (index) {
            widget.pickerModel.setMiddleIndex(index);
          }, (index) {
            setState(() {
              refreshScrollOffset();
              _notifyDateChanged();
            });
          }),
          Text(
            widget.pickerModel.rightDivider(),
            style: theme.itemStyle,
          ),
          _renderColumnView(
              ValueKey(widget.pickerModel.currentMiddleIndex() +
                  widget.pickerModel.currentLeftIndex()),
              theme,
              widget.pickerModel.rightStringAtIndex,
              rightScrollCtrl,
              widget.pickerModel.layoutProportions()[2], (index) {
            widget.pickerModel.setRightIndex(index);
            // Add this lines
             setState(() {
              refreshScrollOffset();
              _notifyDateChanged();
            });
           // -- end of lines
          }, null),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```